# Adding a constructor to the existing class with minimum effect

Tags: java

I face constantly this problem. I do not know, whether my approach is not correct. The code base of the project, for which I work is quiet old and it is not possible to change the current constructor with a builder pattern or static factory because tens of other classes use the current constructor.

Lets say it is current constructor;

```
  // Constructor used until now
  public MatchingPortfolioUtil( Integer parameterA, Integer parameterB, 
  Integer parameterC)
  {
    this.parameterA = parameterA;
    this.parameterB = parameterB;
    this.parameterC = parameterC;
  }
```

and I want to add the following constructor.

```
  // The new constructor
  public MatchingPortfolioUtil(Integer parameterA)
  {
     this.parameterA = parameterA; 
  }
```

until now, everything seems normal but what I want (if possible with a good design) is that the constructor, which I created for my new module, should be only used my new module because it may cause some exceptions if somebody else uses it in another module by thinking this constructor is safe.

Comment: If you  want to use it only in your Project, create a subclass of the existing class und add the constructor there

Comment: @Jens If I create a subclass of the current class, I must use this constructor again with super. I am looking forward to a cleaner solution if any.

Comment: Why you must use the constructor (which) again?

Comment: why not calling the same constructor... new MatchingPortfolioUtil(paramA, null, null); or whatever different from null to a default value..

Comment: @Jens There is only one constructor in the class. If i extend this class, the subclass should call the constructor of the parent class with super. I do not want to call the parent class's constructor.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Exact I do not want to do that. In the example, there are three parameters but in the real code, there are circa 10 parameters and it does not seem to me as clean code if I give null to ten parameters.

Comment: @BernhardColby But this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Jens Then, I blame on the code base, if it does not look clean :)

Comment: @BernhardColby what do you expect the other properties to be when calling your new, single parameter constructor? Is there any code not shown inside or outside the class depending on that other parameters to be not `null`? (If your answer is *don't know* assume *yes* )

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The class is tightly coupled and it is more than 1000 lines of codes. However, I need only one method of the class and for this special method, I do not need other parameters.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes, the class has many responsibility. I think this is the best solution. Would you consider write this as an answer. Thereby, I can accept it as accepted solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class is tightly coupled and it is more than 1000 lines of codes. I need only one method of the class and for this special method, I do not need other parameters.

This sound like the class has to many responsibilities.

I'd suggest to move the method you need to a separate (new) class so that you can use it in separation.